# Drinking alcohol during davening

Tags: halacha, tefilla, intoxication

I am not clear what the rule is for drinking and then davening in the following sense (can be considered a follow to [Drunken Davening](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6394/drunken-davening)).

On the one hand, in the SA 99 we have that someone is not allowed to daven if they have a reviit of wine (or I would assume an equivalent amount of alcohol in a different volume), and for larger volumes, we have that it depends if the person is sober enough to "speak before a king".

We also have the Mishna Berurah there on ד saying that even if one is used to drinking and feels no effects after one reviit of wine, they still may not daven.

What I don't understand is that if one feels no effects, what are they waiting for until they are allowed to pray again?

As an aside, do we use the same standard for getting an aliya in this respect (for both the oleh and the baal koreh)?

Comment: He is waiting the standard amount of time it takes to lose the drunkeness even though he doesn't feel anything

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob ???

Comment: The time it takes to lose drunkeness is the same time as walking a mil, which I if I remember correctly is about one hour

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob Independent of how drunk one is?

Comment: The ramba zl holds that if you drink a ravi3ith you must wait, even if you feel anything or not

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob, the time it takes to walk a mil is somewhere between 18 and 24 minutes.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen sorry your right

Comment: What does chabad use to allow so much drinking on simchas torah? Is that it's own question?

Comment: @andrewmh20 a good question and related, but not the same as what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

The OP asked:

> What I don't understand is that if one feels no effects, what are they waiting for until they are allowed to pray again?

The answer is to look carefully at the Mishnah Berurah in context, as well as the source it quotes. The [Mishnah Berurah (99:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.99.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> עד שיסיר יינו - ואף אם רגיל לשתות הרבה ואינו שיכור כלל ברביעית אפ"ה לא יתפלל לכתחלה אם שתה רביעית יין [ברכי יוסף]:‏
>
> Until his removes his wine - and even if he is used to drinking a lot, and is not "Shikor" at all from a revi'is, even so, he may not pray lechatchila if he drank a revi'is of wine.

The Birkei Yosef (OC 99:1), cited above, notes that this person is not considered a "Shikor", since he is able to speak in front of the king, but rather, simply a "Shasui".
Therefore, he definitely still feels the effects (perhaps he's a little light-headed), but due to his regular drinking, these are not severe symptoms that classify him as a "Shikor":

> שתה כדי רביעית יין וכו'. פירוש אף שהוא רגיל ביין, **שאם שותה הרבה אינו בסוג שיכור, אלא יכול לדבר בפני המלך, ולא קרינן ביה אלא שתוי**, עם כל זה אם שתה רביעית אל יתפלל לכתחילה, וכמו שביאר מרן בב"י דברי הטור, **שכתב שתוי כל שיכול לדבר בפני המלך**, ומ"מ לכתחילה לא יתפלל אפי' אם שתה כדי רביעית. ע"ש. ובב"ח. ודוק.‏

This difference is noted by the Poskim (the Birkei Yosef cites the Beis Yosef here, and the Mishnah Berurah himself mentions this difference, see [99:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.99.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), for example), and in no way unique to the Birkei Yosef.

**Conclusion: Therefore, in this case, he should wait until the wine no longer affects him in any way, and then he may daven.**