# Can one study Torah having drunk wine/being intoxicated?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, intoxication

As explained in this post ([How much alcohol does one need to consume in order to be halachically drunk or intoxicated?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86786/how-much-alcohol-does-one-need-to-consume-in-order-to-be-halachically-drunk-or-i?r=SearchResults)), Gemara presents definitions of having drunk wine and being intoxicated. It answers whether one can pray in either of these two states.

Accordingly, a question arises whether one can study Torah when being in these two states? Is it forbidden as in the case with praying?

Comment: Why would you think that the two contradict?

Comment: @AlBerko I don't think they contradict, just asking)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gemara ([Krisus 13b](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.13b.46-49?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says that it is forbidden to declare the Halacha and to expound on the meaning of the Pesukim that have Halachic repercussions ([see Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Keritot.13b.46-49?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Keritot.13b.47.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en))when drunk. But can learn a Mishna since it is without intent to derive Halacha as we cannot learn Halacha from Mishnayos.

> תנו רבנן (ויקרא י, י) "ולהבדיל בין הקודש ובין החול" אלו דמין וערכין חרמין והקדשות "בין הטמא ובין הטהור" אלו טמאות וטהרות; "ולהורות" זו הוראה; "את כל החוקים" אלו מדרשות; "אשר דבר ה'" זו הלכה; "ביד משה" זה תלמוד. יכול אף המשנה? תלמוד לומר "ולהורות".     ר' יוסי בר' יהודה אומר יכול אף תלמוד? ת"ל "ולהורות"

The [Shach in Yore Dea 242:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.242.13?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en) says **it is permitted for a Drunkard to  learn Torah, Gemora or Midrash (or any other learning where one's intention is not to derive Halacha) as long as *not* learning to derive Halacha** just like one can learn Mishna which one cannot derive Halacha from it. The exception would be a *Poseik* who always learns according to Halacha (though he can learn non halchic material like Agadic Midrash):

> הרמב"ם שם **מותר לשיכור ללמוד תורה ואפילו הלכות ומדרשות והוא שלא יורה** ואם היה חכם וקבוע להוראה לא ילמד שלמודו הוראה היא וכ"כ הב"ח והוא מהש"ס דכריתות וכדאיתא בכסף משנה שם:

The [Rema in Yore Dea 242:13](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.242.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains what it means to make a *Horaah* of Halacha:

> ויזהר כל אדם שלא יורה כשהוא שתוי יין או שאר דברים המשכרים אפי' בדבר פשוט אם לא שהוא דבר ברור בפוסקים וזיל קרי בי רב הוא
>   A person should not Pasken Halacha when drunk with wine or other alchoholic beverages even something that is obvious to him, unless it is something clear in the Poskim and everyone that learns in the Beis hamedrash knows that Halacha in which case it is permitted.

But the Shach and Bach forbid to *pasken* even something clear to everyone in the Beis hamedrash unless it is the clear meaning in the Passuk and the *Tziddukim* would even agree: ([Shach ibid](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.242.13?lang=bi&p2=Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.242.21.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en))

> נראה מבואר דאפילו הוא דבר ברור בפוסקים כל שאינו מפורש במקרא שהצדוקים מודים בו אסור להורות וכ"כ הב"ח