# May a Kohen with Auto-Brewery Syndrome Duchan?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, kohen-priest, choleh-sick, intoxication

This question is related to another question asked ([How much alcohol does one need to consume in order to be halachically drunk or intoxicated?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86786/how-much-alcohol-does-one-need-to-consume-in-order-to-be-halachically-drunk-or-i)).

[Auto-Brewery Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-brewery_syndrome) is a condition in which fungi or bacteria produce intoxicating quantities of ethanol in the stomach, which result in drunkenness.

May a Kohen experiencing Auto-Brewery Syndrome Duchan, or perform any obligations which require him to be sober?

Comment: Since such a person is intoxicated, it would appear not depending on if it can be controlled or not. However, this should be asked of a rav in consultation with a doctor.

Comment: If he is obviously drunk, it seems like it might be the same problem as a kohen with dyed hands.